# Failed Installation attempt of TurtleSim

Tags: ros, simulation, installation, turtlesim, turtlesim-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So, I've tried to install TurtleSim several times now, but to no avail.

I am basically taking over for the main guy that ran this OS, but I'm at a loss of experience with ROS.

Now, to the situation.

I have tried several install attempts according to the tutorials that are on the website, but TurtleSim will not work. When I check for installation, it says that TurtleSim is installed, but when I try to run I get the following script:

rmp@rfm5237-003:~$ rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node [rospack] couldn't find package [turtlesim]

I've searched through the FAQs and several online sections that deal with TurtleSim, but I'm still at a loss. If anyone could give me an answer or point me to where to look, that would be appreciated.

Thanks for the help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10215/failed-installation-attempt-of-turtlesim/) by [jdavidcamacho](https://answers.ros.org/users/673/jdavidcamacho/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-06-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jdavidcamacho](https://answers.ros.org/users/673/jdavidcamacho/) on 2011-06-09**:
You were absolutely correct. A quick installation of the full desktop suite put me right back on track. Thanks alot!

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-06-09**:
I there was an error in the tutorials, I think you need to install ros-diamondback-desktop. Sorry that you had a problem getting things working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I there was an error in the tutorials, I think you need to install ros-diamondback-desktop. Sorry that you had a problem getting things working. - mwise_wg (Jun 09)

You were absolutely correct. A quick installation of the full desktop suite put me right back on track. Thanks alot! - jdavidcamacho (Jun 09)

---

Originally posted by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) with karma: 2915 on 2011-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0